# How to point hostname to ip address when in office?

Tags: macos, networking

I'm doing some work for a small company. Their network is configured such that in the office they use an IP addresses like 192.168.1.100 to access their servers and and from outside they use a host name like server.example.com. I work mostly remotely but I visit the office frequently. On those occasions, when I use server.example.com, it routes the connection the long way around instead of mapping it to the local IP address, which introduces a lot of lag and eats up time.

I don't have enough clout or reputation to get them to reconfigure their network to do what I consider to be the right thing, which is what every other company I've worked for does, which is to map their hosts to the internal addresses correctly on the internal network. My problem is that my entire complex work environment takes time to reconfigure when I shift from host to IP address or back. It would reduce hassle all around if I could tell my mac that the normal server.example.com points to 192.168.1.100 when I am in the office using their wireless network. My gut tells me I should be able to do this, but I lack the networking skill to do it. Any clues on how to do this?

Comment: You could setup a name local to your machine. Try searching: https://www.google.com/search?q=osx+local+host+file&oq=osx+local+host+file

Comment: It seems like that problem is an exact analog for my existing problem. I already have a name that I want to remap. What I need is an OSX way to determine that I'm on the office network and then remap the name to the local address. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Seems weird that someone would downvote/close this question without providing a bit of feedback. Please, if this is trivial then post an answer. If off-topic, explain why. I can't learn if you don't give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what you are looking for:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122893/dynamically-change-etc-hosts

Basically you need to dynamically change your own hosts file so that `server.example.com` resolves to `192.168.1.100` when you are inside the company network, and resolves to the public IP when you are trying to access it from an external location.

I think the simplest way to do this would be to have two hosts files, and simply rename them as necessary.

Comment: That seems like a good general approach, but the linked page doesn't show how to do it on a mac, which doesn't have the linux system structure, and the dhcp scripts don't exist on a mac. I'm looking for some way to detect that I am on a specific network and change the mapping in that case.

Comment: So far I've discovered a nice program called SleepWatcher that detects when your mac wakes from sleep and allows attaching a script to fire what that occurs. When I get a free moment I'll write a script to parse the MAC address out of the default gateway and use that to swap in a new hosts file. I'll post it here as soon as I get time to test it (requires driving to their office).

Comment: @FranK.I thought that it would be quite similar on a MAC because OSX is in fact *nix based, but I guess not. But it looks like you found your hosts file and a good way of triggering the script to change it, so that's good. Please do post your findings. Cheers. :)